# Can I use Schengen business visa from Germany to visit Denmark?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, germany, business-travel, denmark

I am an Indian national and a Permanent Resident (Green Card) of USA. I will be traveling to Germany on Business in March, 2017 and am about to get a Schengen Visa for Business purposes.
Meanwhile, I have an opportunity to visit Denmark as a personal visit in Feb.

Can I used the Schengen visa obtained from the German consulate to visit Denmark? I am a little concerned because I will be visiting Denmark (and returning to USA) before I travel to Germany.

I appreciate any help and pointers. I am confused!

Comment: My take is that you should apply through Denmark and include your complete itinerary, including Germany.  Also you should go for a one year Schengen, you can use your business purpose as your premise. Avoid overthinking this.

Comment: @GayotFow, in this case, the main destination would be Germany, but Denmark will be next month. Any mixup regarding the right consulate might make it too late.

Comment: @o.m. I hear you, my take still stands :)